# Spring Boot Test Error: Failed to Load ApplicationContext - Not a Managed Type

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm running a Spring Boot test and encountering an IllegalStateException with the message "Failed to load ApplicationContext." The test fails due to an error related to bean creation, specifically with the UserModel class not being recognized as a managed entity type. Below is the relevant part of the stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
...

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userController'
...

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userService'
...

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository'
...

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.alphaomegazed.aoz_apartments.model.UserModel
```

The error indicates that the UserModel is not a managed type. This class is referenced by the userRepository, which is in turn used by the userService and ultimately by the userController.

I've checked that the UserModel class is annotated with @Entity and located within the package scanned by @EnableJpaRepositories. Yet, the application fails to start within the test context. Any help to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Here is my @Entity class:

```
package com.alphaomegazed.aoz_apartments.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType; //included for identity strategy
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue; //corrected import instead of javax.annotation

@Entity
public class UserModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    // Getters-------------------------------------------------
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    // Setters-------------------------------------------------
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Here is my @Repository class for reference:

```
package com.alphaomegazed.aoz_apartments.repository_interfaces;

import com.alphaomegazed.aoz_apartments.model.UserModel; //to be accessed
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import java.util.Optional; //this is part of the java.util package, but it needs to be included

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<UserModel, Long> {

    // Used by UserDetailService to define wether or not the user exists
    Optional<UserModel> findByUsername(String username);

    Boolean existsByUsername(String username);
}
```

Here is the test class for reference:

```
package com.alphaomegazed.aoz_apartments;

import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class AozApartmentsApplicationTests {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }
}
```

What might be causing UserModel to not be recognized as a managed entity, and how can I resolve this issue to successfully run my test?

Comment: Depending on the Spring Boot version you might need to change the `javax.persistence` imports into `jakarta.persistence` . Check the related questions for more info.

Comment: Please put your controller and service code